# Dropout on a Dense layer

Tags: keras, neural-network, dropout

In Keras, when we define our first hidden layer with `input_dim` argument followed by a Dropout layer as follows:

```
model.add(Dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', input_dim = 5))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Is the Dropout being applied to the hidden or to the input layer? If it is being applied to the hidden, how can i apply to the input one aswell and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dropout is applied to the output of the previous layer, so in this case to the hidden layer.
If you want to apply it to the input, add a Dropout layer as your first layer in the network.

Comment: I see, this was confusing me, because in Keras documentation says "Applies Dropout to the input."

Comment: I think they mean it applies the dropout to its own input, which is usually the output of the previous layer.